# Why won't GeoJSON load?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I'm working with openlayers3 and I wanted to load a GeoJSON file from my local `../assets/data/countries.geojson`. Nothing is wrong but it didn't appear on the screen.

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vector Examples</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script src="../assets/ol3/js/ol.js"></script>
    <script>




var originalSource=new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: new ol.source.Vector({
   projection : 'EPSG:3857',
      url: '../assets/data/countries.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({

         defaultDataProjection :'EPSG:4326', 
         projection: 'EPSG:3857'

      })
   })
});

      var center = ol.proj.transform([0, 0], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

      var view = new ol.View({
        center: center,
        zoom: 2
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [originalSource],
        view: view
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you introduce projections here? Default behaviour should work.  You can copy code from http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/examples/vector-layer.html and change URL to your geojson file to see if it solves your issue.

Comment: You also have have a reference to OpenLayers 3 library twice e.g `<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/build/ol.js"></script>` and `<script src="../assets/ol3/js/ol.js"></script>`

Comment: i already tried the example that openlayers offer when i used with chrome it gives the cross origin error and with mozilla no mistakes but still the vector won't load

Comment: To not care about cross origin error > http://wiki.sln.suny.edu/display/SLNKB/Enabling+mixed+content+in+Google+Chrome

Comment: still the same problem i think the problem is in the extent when i used vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent(); it gives me 
[Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity]

Comment: Remove all projections parts please e.g `projection : 'EPSG:3857',`, `defaultDataProjection :'EPSG:4326', ` and `projection: 'EPSG:3857'` Your `[Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity]` is due to wrong reprojection on EPSG 3857 coordinates.

Comment: i did it gives only the zoom in and out botton and a blank page no data i can zoom in and out so there is somthing but i can't see it and the extent still [Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity]

Comment: Do you run your sample on a server? Is the path is `file:///tmp/sample.html` instead of `http://localhost/sample.html`? In first case, it would never work. You must run your sample on a webserver. Otherwise, you will be unable to load your GeoJSON and the extent will always be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things that I did not know about when I started to use JavaScript map libraries like OpenLayers was when a file is loaded from a file system verses a web server. In my early days with OpenLayers, I would try try the OL examples and wonder why they worked on the OpenLayers site but did not work off off c:\user or /user/myid/olfiles.  The rude thing that I did not understand was why say, a txt file, would work being served off a local file system but not, say, a GeoJSON example.  Then I realized that you needed a webserver for some layers file types and not others.  You need to have an apache webserver for the geojson/kml examples or something like http://brackets.io/ editor that allows you to run your example OpenLayers.js file from a local file system.  The long story short:  You cannot open a GeoJSON file with a file:// type url.  You'd also have the same problems with LEAF.js.